# Ubuntu 16.04.1 and bluetooth soundspeaker JBL Charge 2+, sound is very poor

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth-speaker

I have purchased a bluetooth speaker and have successfully connected it to laptop. Sound is very poor via bluetooth. Via 3.5mm jack is very nice.

I had to install blueman for communicating with JBL. Pair was OK. Sound profile is: HSP/HPF. Change to A2DP sink not works: Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink.

Sound speaker: JBL charge 2+
Device: Dell N2-5559-N2-522K-Silver
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1
Kernel: 4.4.0-45-generic

Sound via bluetooth and Windows 10 is OK. Why has sound a poor quality?
Thank you.

Comment: Please refrain from uploading unknown files to file hosting services and linking them here; we have no way from the link alone to verify that this is an 'ok' file or is malware (nor would we be able to even if we knew the file extension or type), and the site you've linked to requires signup for people to access files. (As a result I removed the link and the reference to the sound file, which is no longer available)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Can i post link to my FTP to sound file or not? How can i upload file for detailed information to this post? Thank you.